# Difference between .jar file and .java file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am trying to compile my java project I have coded in Eclipse, using the `javac <name>.java` command in the terminal on mac. However, when I export the project I have created, it is exported as a `.jar` file. Can anyone tell me how to convert this to a java file, how to export the project as a `.java` file, or simply the difference between a `.jar` file and `.java` file?

Comment: In short: java File --> source code, jar file --> zip archive of compiled sources

Comment: Google would help in such cases! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)

Answer (score 5):

A .jar-file is a Zip archive containing one or multilple java class files. This makes the usage of libraries (consisting of multiple classes) more handy. Directories and .jar-files are added to the classpath and available to the `ClassLoader` at runtime to find particular classes inside of it. **JAR = Java ARchive**.
A .java-file contains Java code. A Java file is compiled to produce a class file that can be loaded by the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the `.java` files are the source-code, and `.jar` files contain the compressed and packaged compiled .class files.